# Threadsafe data structures in servlets

Tags: java, multithreading, servlets, thread-safety, jersey

I have the following thread in a servlet which accepts a ConcurrentHashMap in its constructor.

```
RequestThread(ConcurrentHashMap<String, String[]> sentRequests, ServletContext context) {
        this.sentRequests = sentRequests;
        this.context = context;
    }
```

Multiple users access the ConcurrentHashMap. It is supposed to be used across all the classes.

Is it **thread safe** to pass ConcurrentHashMap in such a way or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: I would use a cache library that handles the objects through all the application instead trying to reinvent the wheel. Some examples are ehcache and infinispan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case it is important that `ConcurrentHashMap` is thread safe. It is not important how will you pass it around.
And according to [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html):

> A hash table supporting full concurrency of retrievals and adjustable
>   expected concurrency for updates. This class obeys the same functional
>   specification as Hashtable, and includes versions of methods
>   corresponding to each method of Hashtable. However, even though all
>   operations are thread-safe, retrieval operations do not entail
>   locking, and there is not any support for locking the entire table in
>   a way that prevents all access. This class is fully interoperable with
>   Hashtable in programs that rely on its thread safety but not on its
>   synchronization details.